# system hangs at glReadPixel() call

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

I am calling `glReadPixel` after a `glDrawArray` call. I am rendering a geometry with 3D texture on it as a target `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`. The problem is my system hangs at the `glReadPixel call:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, GetViewportWidth(), GetViewportHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)rendered_pixels);
```

When I use target as `GL_TEXTURE_3D` the issue does not occur and it correctly reads the framebuffer contents.

I am using SNORM textures with GL_byte data in `glTeximage3D` call and I am not calling `glPixelStorei`, is it because of this? What should be the parameter for pixelstore call?

Comment: We need to see a bit more of code. Ideally you would post coda of a smallest fully functional example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` should be `(4)` by default, so assuming `rendered_pixels` is aligned to a 4-byte boundary, the call shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: What exactly is "system hangs"? If that means there is a noticeable delay, that is normal. Unless you read into a buffer object, `glReadPixels` _must_ stall and wait for both the rendering to finish and the complete DMA transfer (which can possibly be a noticeable moment). Or, does "system hangs" really mean _the system hangs_, i.e. nothing works at all any more and you must press the reset button?